# Extract two rows out of dataframe - r

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I extract two rows (rows `a` and `b` below) from my data frame `df`?

```
df1 = df[(df$column1 == "a" & "b"),]
```

Comment: df1 = df[df$column1 %in% c("a", "b"),]

Comment: or `df1 <- subset(df, column1 %in% c("a", "b"))` or `df1 <- dplyr::filter(df, column1 %in% c("a", "b"))`

Comment: Are `"a"` and `"b"` values in `column1` or are they row names?  If the latter, you can do `df[c("a","b"),]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the subset function: `subset(df, subset = column1 %in% c("a","b"))`

Regards.